# Complicated COUNT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find the number of video credits a particular user has.

The following are the three tables that are relevant:

```
CREATE TABLE `userprofile_userprofile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   ...
 )

CREATE TABLE `userprofile_videoinfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  KEY `userprofile_videoinfo_e43a31e7` (`uploaded_by_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `uploaded_by_id_refs_id_492ba9396be0968c` FOREIGN KEY (`uploaded_by_id`) REFERENCES `userprofile_userprofile` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `userprofile_videocredit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `userprofile_videocredit_fa26288c` (`video_id`),
  KEY `userprofile_videocredit_141c6eec` (`profile_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `profile_id_refs_id_31fc4a6405dffd9f` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `userprofile_userprofile` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `video_id_refs_id_4dcff2eeed362a80` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `userprofile_videoinfo` (`id`)
)
```

The `videoinfo` table is when a user uploads a video, he will get an "uploaded_by" listing. The `videocredit` table are all the credits for a given film. It is entirely independent of uploading the film (i.e., a video can be uploaded by a user without crediting himself, and a user can be credited in a video he has not uploaded).

In trying to find the COUNT of videos a user has been credited in, I want to find:

```
# videos a user has uploaded + # of non duplicate-video credits uploaded by others
```

By way of example: if a user uploads 5 videos called:

```
VideoME1, VideoME2, VideoME3, VideoME4, and VideoME5 
(total = 5 videos [`videoinfo.uploaded_by_id`])
```

And has the following video credits:

```
VideoME1 (4 credits - director, writer, editor, choreographer)
VideoME2 (1 credit)
VideoOTHER1 (2 credits - writer, editor)
VideoOTHER2 (1 credit - writer)
(total = 8 video credits [`videocredit.profile_id`])
```

The COUNT should be 5 (videos uploaded) + 2 (non-duplicate video credits uploaded by others) = 7. If a user has no video credits, it should = 0 (i.e., `LEFT OUTER JOIN`).

I've been able to figure out the COUNTS for each of the uploads/credits, but can't figure out how to combine the two and get rid of duplicates. What SQL do I need to do this? Thank you.

By the way, this is what I currently have for each (individual) COUNT:

```
mysql> SELECT full_name, v.video_id, COUNT(DISTINCT v.video_id) as cnt
    -> FROM userprofile_userprofile u LEFT OUTER JOIN userprofile_videocredit v
    -> ON u.id = V.profile_id
    -> GROUP BY full_name
    -> ORDER BY cnt DESC;

mysql> SELECT full_name, v.id, COUNT(v.uploaded_by_id) as cnt
    -> FROM userprofile_userprofile u LEFT OUTER JOIN userprofile_videoinfo v
    -> ON u.id = v.uploaded_by_id
    -> GROUP BY full_name
    -> ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-Zero's suggestion of adding an "uploader credit" to the data is the best way to keep the query simple.  If that's not an option, do an inner join between userprofile_videoinfo and userprofile_videocredit to make it easy to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT u.id, u.full_name, COUNT(DISTINCT v.video_id) as credit_count
FROM userprofile_userprofile u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT vi.video_id, vi.uploaded_by_id, vc.profile_id as credited_to_id
    FROM userprofile_videoinfo vi
    JOIN userprofile_videocredit vc ON vi.id = vc.video_id
    ) v ON u.id = v.uploaded_by_id OR u.id = v.credited_to_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.full_name
ORDER BY credit_count DESC
```

The subquery may be useful to create as a view.

Comment: great, one type: `vi.video_id` should be `v.id` (there are two cases of it, L1 and L3). I think I'll set up a new column for count, but just wanted to see how to do that particular SQL query. Thank you!

Comment: +1, thanks for making me think more about what was really being asked.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 ways to do this:
1) Add 'uploader' as something they can be credited for, and add a trigger to autopopulate the entry - only one table to go for, etc.
2) I believe the following query should also work (which will also take care of your `full_name` problem):

```
WITH credit_rollup (profile_id) as (SELECT profile_id
                                    FROM userprofile_videocredit 
                                    GROUP BY profile_id, video_id)
SELECT full_name, COALESCE((SELECT count(*) 
                            FROM credit_rollup as v
                            WHERE v.profile_id = u.id), 0) +
                  COALESCE((SELECT count(*)
                            FROM userprofile_videoinfo as v
                            WHERE v.uploaded_by_id = u.id), 0) as credits
FROM userprofile_userprofile
ORDER by credits DESC
```

Although, you may wish to remove 'userprofile' from in front of every table name, and just put them in a schema with that name.

---

Edited query to only count 1 credit per video.

---

After reviewing the post one more time, it has become apparent that I missed a key use of the word 'duplicate' - in that the user was only credited once for uploading the video AND having some sort of credit in the video (director, editor, etc.), but not twice (which is an OR).
As such, the following query is more in line (and thanks to @simon for making me think about it):

```
WITH credit_rollup (uploaded_by_id, credited_to_id) 
                   AS (SELECT info.uploaded_by_id, credit.profile_id
                       FROM userprofile_videoinfo as info
                       JOIN userprofile_videocredit as credit
                       ON info.id = credit.video_id
                       GROUP BY info.uploaded_by_id, credit.profile_id)
SELECT usr.full_name, COALSECE((SELECT count(*)
                                 FROM credit_rollup as rollup
                                 WHERE rollup.uploaded_by_id = usr.id
                                 OR rollup.credited_to_id = usr.id), 0) as credits
FROM userprofile as usr
ORDER BY credits DESC
```

As @simon said, the CTE (he used a subquery) may be useful to create as a view (basically, it lists everybody *once* for their involvment in a video, a handy thing to have).

Comment: this doesn't account for duplicates. For example, if I have ten credits in one video the above COUNT query will = 10 instead of, what it should, 1.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. The query isn't quite working, but I am going to try and figure out where the syntax error is (though my inclination is it has to do with the `credited_to_id`.

Comment: I'd left off the `FROM` clause in the main query, and `user` is a reserved word... Doh!

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't made any mistake:

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.full_name
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM userprofile_videoinfo vi
         WHERE u.id = vi.uploaded_by_id
       ) AS cnt_VideosUploadedBy                         <---- 5
    , cnt_Credits_InMyUploads 
        + cnt_Videos_CreditedIn - cnt_Videos_CreditedIn_and_UploadBy
      AS cnt_Difficult                               <---- 5 + 4 - 2 = 7
    , cnt_Credits_Total                                  <---- 8
    , cnt_Credits_InMyUploads                            <---- 5
    , cnt_Videos_CreditedIn                              <---- 4 
    , cnt_Videos_CreditedIn_and_UploadBy                 <---- 2
FROM userprofile_userprofile u 
  LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT u.id
             , COUNT(vc.video_id)
               AS cnt_Credits_Total
             , (COUNT(vi.profile)
               AS cnt_Credits_InMyUploads
             , COUNT(DISTINCT vc.video_id)
               AS cnt_Videos_CreditedIn
             , (COUNT(DISTINCT vi.id)
               AS cnt_Videos_CreditedIn_and_UploadBy
        FROM userprofile_userprofile u 
          JOIN userprofile_videocredit vc
            ON u.id = vc.profile_by_id
          LEFT JOIN userprofile_videoinfo vi
            ON vc.video_id = vi.id
            AND vi.profile = u.id
        GROUP BY u.id
      ) AS grp
    ON grp.id = u.id
```