# SQL Count over multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate

This is a follow-up to this previous question: [Complicated COUNT query in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580684/complicated-count-query-in-mysql). None of the answers worked under all conditions, and I have had trouble figuring out a solution as well. I will be awarding a 75 point bounty to the first person that provides a fully correct answer (I will award the bounty as soon as it is available, and as reference I've done this before: [Improving Python/django view code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245755/improving-python-django-view-code)).

I want to get the count of video credits a user has and not allow duplicates (i.e., for every video a user can be credited in it 0 or 1 times. I want to find three counts: the number of videos a user has uploaded (easy) -- `Uploads`; the number of videos credited in from videos not uploaded by the user -- `Credited_by_others`; and the total number of videos a user has been credited in -- `Total_credits`.

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `userprofile_userprofile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   ...
 )

CREATE TABLE `videos_video` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  KEY `userprofile_video_e43a31e7` (`uploaded_by_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `uploaded_by_id_refs_id_492ba9396be0968c` FOREIGN KEY (`uploaded_by_id`) REFERENCES `userprofile_userprofile` (`id`)
)
```

**Note that the `uploaded_by_id` is the same as the `userprofile.id`**

```
CREATE TABLE `videos_videocredit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL
  ...
  KEY `videos_videocredit_fa26288c` (`video_id`),
  KEY `videos_videocredit_141c6eec` (`profile_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `profile_id_refs_id_31fc4a6405dffd9f` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `userprofile_userprofile` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `video_id_refs_id_4dcff2eeed362a80` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `videos_video` (`id`)
)
```

Here is a step-by-step to illustrate:

1) create 2 users:

```
insert into userprofile_userprofile (id, full_name) values (1, 'John Smith');
insert into userprofile_userprofile (id, full_name) values (2, 'Jane Doe');
```

2) a user uploads a video. He does not yet credit anyone -- including himself -- in it.

```
insert into videos_video (id, title, uploaded_by_id) values (1, 'Hamlet', 1);
```

The result should be as follows:

```
**User**     **Uploads**  **Credited_by_others**  **Total_credits**
John Smith       1                0                      1
Jane Doe         0                0                      0
```

3) the user who uploaded the video now credits himself in the video. Note this should not change anything, since the user has already received a credit for uploading the film and I am not allowing duplicate credits:

```
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (1, 1, 1, 'director')
```

The result should now be as follows:

```
**User**     **Uploads**  **Credited_by_others**  **Total_credits**
John Smith       1                0                      1
Jane Doe         0                0                      0
```

4) The user now credits himself two more times in the same video (i.e., he has had multiple 'positions' in the video). In addition, he credits Jane Doe three times for that video:

```
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (2, 1, 1, 'writer')
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (3, 1, 1, 'producer')
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (4, 1, 2, 'director')
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (5, 1, 2, 'editor')
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (6, 1, 2, 'decorator')
```

The result should now be as follows:

```
**User**     **Uploads**  **Credited_by_others**  **Total_credits**
John Smith       1                0                      1
Jane Doe         0                1                      1
```

5) Jane Doe now uploads a video. She does not credit herself, but credits John Smith twice in the video:

```
insert into videos_video (id, title, uploaded_by_id) values (2, 'Othello', 2)
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (7, 2, 1, 'writer')
insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (8, 2, 1, 'producer')
```

The result should now be as follows:

```
**User**     **Uploads**  **Credited_by_others**  **Total_credits**
John Smith       1                1                      2
Jane Doe         1                1                      2
```

So, I would like to find those three fields for each user -- `Uploads`, `Credited_by_others`, and `Total_credits`. Data should never be Null, but instead be 0 when the field has no count. Thank you.

Comment: Under (5), should it be `(7, 2, 1)` and `(8, 2, 1)`?

Comment: To clarify again, Jane receives credit merely for uploading, correct? She is not required to be explicitly credited in her own uploads?

Comment: Correct. Uploading a video automatically gives a credit to the user who uploaded the video. So if someone uploads a video, it doesn't matter if they are credited 0 times or 1000 times in that video, they will still receive one credit for it. (As a side note, only individuals who are involved in the making of a video will be able to upload it, so for example, videos will not be uploaded by random individuals with no involvement in the video.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the query using joins, so it would become easier for the server to optimize.

First two views to simplify the query

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS vperson_videos AS
    SELECT
        v.uploaded_by_id AS id,
        COUNT(*) AS uploads
    FROM vvideo v
    GROUP BY v.uploaded_by_id;
```

The above view just counts the number of videos which where uploaded by the user.

```
CREATE VIEW vperson_credits AS
    SELECT
        c.profile_id AS id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.video_id) AS credits
    FROM vcredit c
    INNER JOIN vvideo cv ON cv.id = c.video_id
    WHERE cv.uploaded_by_id <> c.profile_id
    GROUP BY c.profile_id;
```

The above view counts the number of (distinct) videos which where credited to the user, but ignoring those that the user has uploaded himself.

Then the query itself:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.full_name,
    IFNULL(pv.uploads,0) AS uploads,
    IFNULL(pc.credits,0) AS credits,
    IFNULL(pv.uploads,0) + IFNULL(pc.credits,0) AS total_credits
FROM vperson p
LEFT OUTER JOIN vperson_videos pv ON pv.id = p.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vperson_credits pc ON pc.id = p.id;
```

I used `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include those users who has not uploaded any video or not been credited in any. `IFNULL()` was necessary because I would get `NULL` instead of `0`.

The final result is:

```
+----+------------+---------+---------+---------------+
| id | full_name  | uploads | credits | total_credits |
+----+------------+---------+---------+---------------+
|  1 | John Smith |       1 |       1 |             2 | 
|  2 | Jane Doe   |       1 |       1 |             2 | 
+----+------------+---------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The total credit is just the sum as the credit-by-upload and the foreign credit. Since credit-by-upload is easy, here is just the foreign credit. Hold your breath for two-fold subquery.

```
SELECT profile_id, COUNT(video_id) AS foreign_credit
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT profile_id, video_id FROM videos_videocredit
             WHERE (profile_id, video_id) NOT IN (SELECT uploaded_by_id, id FROM videos_video)) AS crsq
GROUP BY profile_id;
```

---

This becomes more palpable with a view. We make a view that selects only pairs `(profile_id, video_id)` of people credited in videos which they did not upload themselves. Let's call the view `vfcredits`.

```
CREATE VIEW vfcredits AS
  SELECT DISTINCT profile_id, video_id FROM videos_credit
  WHERE (profile_id, video_id) NOT IN (SELECT uploaded_by_id, id FROM videos_video);
```

Now we can happily paste this into the main query that aggregates foreign credits:

```
SELECT profile_id, COUNT(video_id) AS foreign_credit
FROM vfcredits
GROUP BY profile_id;
```

---

Now let's put it all together. We make two more views, one to count own credits and one to count foreign credits:

```
CREATE VIEW vowncount AS
  SELECT uploaded_by_id AS profile_id, COUNT(*) AS own_credits
  FROM videos_video
  GROUP BY uploaded_by_id;

CREATE VIEW vforeigncount AS
  SELECT profile_id, COUNT(video_id) AS foreign_credits
  FROM vfcredits
  GROUP BY profile_id;
```

Finally, the complete selection:

```
SELECT name,
       own_credits,
       foreign_credits,
       own_credits + foreign_credits AS total_credits
FROM userprofile_userprofile
JOIN vowncount ON(userprofile_userprofile.id = vowncount.profile_id)
JOIN vforeigncount ON(userprofile_userprofile.id = vforeigncount.profile_id);
```

Comment: (Thanks for the edit, in my test setup I had tables "vperson", "vuploads" and "vcredits" -- I found "userprofile_userprofile" a tiny but hard on the fingers and editor window :-))

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you have a couple of mistakes in your problem description.

- In step 5, you describe Jane crediting John twice in video 2.  I think you just got some columns mis-ordered in the values clause.  It should be:

  ```
  insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (7, 2, 1, 'writer');
  insert into videos_videocredit (id, video_id, profile_id, position) values (8, 2, 1, 'producer');
  ```
- Your results should show John credited in 2 videos, and Jane credited in 1 video.

  ```
  +------------+---------+--------------------+---------------+
  | full_name  | Uploads | Credited_by_others | Total_credits |
  +------------+---------+--------------------+---------------+
  | John Smith |       1 |                  1 |             2 | 
  | Jane Doe   |       1 |                  1 |             1 | 
  +------------+---------+--------------------+---------------+
  ```

I tested the following query on MySQL 5.1.57 and it gives the above result.

```
SELECT
  u.full_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT myvideos.id) AS Uploads,
  COUNT(DISTINCT byothers.id) AS Credited_by_others,
  COUNT(DISTINCT credited.id) AS Total_credits
FROM userprofile_userprofile AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_video AS myvideos ON myvideos.uploaded_by_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  videos_videocredit AS c USE INDEX (videocredit_profileid_videoid)
  INNER JOIN videos_video AS credited
    ON c.video_id = credited.id
) ON c.profile_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_video AS byothers USE INDEX (video_up_id)
  ON c.video_id = byothers.id
  AND byothers.uploaded_by_id <> u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

I created a couple of additional indexes and gave the query hints to use them.

```
CREATE INDEX video_up_id ON videos_video (id,uploaded_by_id);

CREATE INDEX videocredit_profileid_videoid ON videos_videocredit (profile_id,video_id);
```

This ensures that all tables (except userprofile) are accessed with the *Using index* mode, which means it can satisfy the query by reading only the index B-trees, without needing to read the table data.  Here's the EXPLAIN report:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: u
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: myvideos
         type: ref
possible_keys: userprofile_video_e43a31e7
          key: userprofile_video_e43a31e7
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.u.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ref
possible_keys: videocredit_profileid_videoid
          key: videocredit_profileid_videoid
      key_len: 5
          ref: test.u.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: credited
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,video_up_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.c.video_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: byothers
         type: ref
possible_keys: video_up_id
          key: video_up_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.c.video_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Optimization can give variable reports when testing against a trivial number of rows.  So we may see different results when testing against a real collection of data, and then it may become unnecessary to give the `USE INDEX` hints.

---

However, in spite of the solution above, I would hope do each task in a separate query.  Doing everything in one query is complex to develop and test, and often costly for the RDBMS to execute.  It will be even more complex if you need to add another count.

```
SELECT
  u.full_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT myvideos.id) AS Uploads
FROM userprofile_userprofile AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_video AS myvideos ON myvideos.uploaded_by_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;

SELECT
  u.full_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT byothers.id) AS Credited_by_others
FROM userprofile_userprofile AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_videocredit AS c
  USE INDEX (videocredit_profileid_videoid)
  ON c.profile_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_video AS byothers
  USE INDEX (video_up_id)
  ON c.video_id = byothers.id AND byothers.uploaded_by_id <> u.id
GROUP BY u.id;

SELECT
  u.full_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT credited.id) AS Total_credits
FROM userprofile_userprofile AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  videos_videocredit AS c
  USE INDEX (videocredit_profileid_videoid)
  INNER JOIN videos_video AS credited
    ON c.video_id = credited.id
) ON c.profile_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: uploading a video is counts as a video credit for the uploader, so when Jane uploads the second video, she receives a second credit, and her final credit count will be 2.

Comment: Just read over and tested the answer. Wow, incredible helpful and descriptive answer -- thank you! Only issue is the one mentioned in previous comment, where a video upload counts as a credit (even if the user doesn't already credit himself in that video).